propagate env vars into the subcomands of a target in Makefile
I have a python file like this
MONGODB_SETTINGS = {
        "connect": False,
        "port": int(os.environ.get("MONGODB_DB_PORT", 27017)),
        "db": os.environ.get("MONGODB_DB_NAME", "foo"),
        "host": os.environ.get("MONGODB_HOST", "127.0.0.1"),
        "authentication_source": os.environ.get("MONGODB_AUTHSRC", "admin"),
        "username": os.environ.get("MONGODB_USERNAME"),
        "password": os.environ.get("MONGODB_PASSWORD"),
    }

which I cannot change (for example using dotenv library).
I also have a Makefile like this:
...
admin: ## Equals to create an admin
    echo $(MONGODB_DB_PORT)
    @ flask admin
...

and also a .env file like this:
MONGODB_DB_PORT=27018

I use include .env at the top of my Makefile but it does not propagate the envs to the subcommand in the target. So when the flask admin runs, the port of the db is still 27017. It's good to notice that there are many env vars in my file, so I cannot do some soulution for one variable. How can I propagate the vars in the .env file to the subcommands in the target.

There is no good way to propagate all the variables set in the .env file without listing them out.
If you have a list of them you can do this:
 export VAR1 VAR2 VAR3 ...

for each VARN you wan to export.
If you really want to do it without listing them, and since your .env file has a regular syntax, you can try this:
export $(shell sed -n 's/=.*//p' .env)

and see if it works (not tested).
